# How do I convert my constant into a timezone?

Tags: python, python-3.x, timezone, date-math

I'm using Python 3.7.  I have this defined in my settings file ...

```
TIME_ZONE = 'America/New York'
```

I want to make the "now()" function timezone aware, so I can do some date subtraction ...

```
int(round((datetime.now(settings.TIME_ZONE) - article.created_on).total_seconds() / 60)) > 10
```

But I keep getting this error

```
TypeError: tzinfo argument must be None or of a tzinfo subclass, not type 'str'
```

How do I convert my constant into a timezone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `pytz` library.

```py
tz = pytz.timezone(TIME_ZONE)
```

This will give you a tzinfo object that you can pass to `.now()`